# Show errormessages on wrong username/password on custom loginform?

Tags: functions, users, login, errors, wp-login-form

I use this simple HTML loginform in my sidebar. Does anyone have any clever way to make it show the errormessages when you type in wrong password or username?

```
<form action="<?php echo wp_login_url(get_permalink()); ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="log" id="log" style="width:92%; margin-bottom:3px;" value="Username" onfocus="if(this.value=='Username')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username'" />
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" style="width:92%; margin-bottom:3px;" value="Password" onfocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Password'" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not use the default function `wp_login_form()` for the login form, example:

```
global $user_login;

if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo __( 'Hello', 'theme_text_domain' ) . $user_login . '<a href="' . wp_logout_url() . '" title="' . __( 'Logout', 'theme_text_domain' ) . '">' . __( 'Logout', FB_BASIS_TEXTDOMAIN ) . '</a>';
} else {
    wp_login_form();
}
```

the function and his params, more information on [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form)

```
wp_login_form(array(
    'echo' => true,
    'redirect' => site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), 
    'form_id' => 'loginform',
    'label_username' => __('Username'),
    'label_password' => __('Password'),
    'label_remember' => __('Remember Me'),
    'label_log_in' => __('Log In'),
    'id_username' => 'user_login',
    'id_password' => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
    'remember' => true,
    'value_username' => ,
    'value_remember' => false
))
```

Comment: this form just redirects to /wp-login.php to show error message. What I´m trying to do is get the errormessage directly above the form

Comment: the function have the param `redirect` and you can set a adress, as example the current site, where you login: `'redirect' => site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),`

Comment: yes, but the messages are still not showing, but I managed to make a page with a custom "login error" text on it, but the best solution would be to include a small message right above the loginform or something. But thanks for the help so far